# How to remove millions of emails from Google Workspaces account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm trying to cleanup a Google Workspaces account in order to archive it.

The issue is that this account has accumulated millions of system generated logging emails since it was setup, and removing these emails is proving to be quite problematic.

The official process seems to be "select all", "select all ### messages in [LABEL]" and then click the rubbish icon.

However this appears to only delete ~20k emails per request. It just won't work for deleting over 5 million emails. It will take far too long.

I also tried using a script to do it at https://script.google.com/

This wasn't much better. It was extremely slow, and times out after about a minute.

Is there some trick to do this more efficiently with extremely large numbers of emails?

I have global admin access for the Workspaces domain if that helps.